# tcolorbox parameter on condition

Tags: tcolorbox, conditionals, code

I wanted to make a tcolorbox, that centers based on the value of a variable (`\standardboxwidth`). I want to call the parameter center for the tcbset only if `\standardboxwidth` is not equal to `\linewidth`. I looked through the documentation, but couldn't find a solution. Can someone help me?

Here is a small code-snippet of my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\def\standardboxwidth{0.5\linewidth}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    width = \standardboxwidth,
    center, %  Only call, if \standardboxwidth != \linewidth
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
    Text
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not following - centering, where the thing you are centering is the same length as the container within which it is being centered is the same as not centering. So it does that anyway.

Comment: My actual code is too long to post here. Therefore I only posted a small example, so that someone can help me better. My question remains: Is it possible to activate a tcbset parameter using a condition (e.g. if else?) and how I can do it for the variable standardboxwidth? (In my actual code I got a problem with center after a parameter for left. It overwrites that parameter. That's ok, if \standardboxwidth != \linewidth, but not if \standardboxwidth = \linewidth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own style using `\tcbset` based on a condition.

Below I define the style `My Center Style` depending on the condition that `\UseCenter` is defined. If it is then `center` is applied, otherwise `center` is *not* applied.

#### Code

```
\def\UseCenter{}%
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\def\standardboxwidth{0.5\linewidth}

\ifdefined\UseCenter
    \tcbset{My Center Style/.style={center}}
\else
    \tcbset{My Center Style/.style={}}
\fi

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    width = \standardboxwidth,
    My Center Style, 
}


\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
    Text
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah nice, that's a good idea. I thought about defining two whole tcbsets, one with center and one without, but that was to much code. Obviously this is a way better idea! I should have seen that, too xD Thank you very much!